# Create Zip File w/ variable string name Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, zip, filenames

I am creating a zip file whose name will be based on a GIT repo hash value and date/time.  So far I have been able to create the zip file successfully, but naming the zip file based off of a variable doesn't seem to work as the child_process.execFile seems to only use a string literal for the name.  See below:

```html
const child_process = require('child_process').execFile;

const repoHash = (`git -C ./repository/myRepository show-ref --hash refs/heads/master`);
const timestamp = Date.now() - 14400000;
const date = new Date(timestamp);
const iso = date.toISOString().match(/(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/);
const revision = child_process(repoHash).toString().trim();
const myTStamp = '_' + iso[1] + '_' + iso[2] + ".zip";

//Below zipName Resolves to "05baf31c20d15edb2c477fa4e7bd2427504d3dba_2020-04-09_13:27:26.zip"
const zipName = revision+myTStamp;  
const sourceDir = "./repository/myRepository";

//Works using a string literal and specifying name "./newZip.zip"
const newFile = () => {
    child_process('zip', ['-r', "./newZip.zip", sourceDir], function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
};

newFile();

//Does Not Work using "zipName" variable
const newFile = () => {
    child_process('zip', ['-r', zipName, sourceDir], function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
};

newFile();
```

Any ideas on how I can get this zip file named appropriately would be appreciated.

Comment: It's possible there's something wrong with the filename, maybe it contains invalid characters? Have you tried putting the full value of zipName into the literal in your first function? Does that work? Does the second function return an error? What is the error?

Comment: Wow...my noob'ness is showing...can't believe I didn't think about that....Yes!  It doesn't like the date/time...Once I took that out, then I was able to use the variable.....Let me see what "typeof" date/time is and convert to string if it is an object.....Thanks...this was very helpful....

Comment: Happy to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

As Dr_Derp said in their comment, I had to remove the ":" from the time.  What I ended up doing is replacing the ":" with "_" see below:

```html
const repoHash = (`git -C ./repository/myRepository show-ref --hash refs/heads/master`);
const timestamp = Date.now() - 14400000;
const date = new Date(timestamp);
const iso = date.toISOString().match(/(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/);
const revision = child_process(repoHash).toString().trim(); 
const sourceDir = "./repository/myRepository";

//Added 2 more variables to make it easier to read though new variables were not necessary
const time = iso[2].replace(/:/g, "_");
const date = iso[1];
//Output of "myTStamp" below:  05baf31c20d15edb2c477fa4e7bd2427504d3dba_DATE_2020-04-09_TIME_14_54_15.zip
const myTStamp = '_DATE_' + date + '_TIME_' + time + ".zip";
const zipName = revision+myTStamp;

const newFile = () => {
    child_process('zip', ['-r', zipName, sourceDir], function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
};

newFile();
```

Thanks again Dr_Derp!